# Android Sugar ORM select sublist from database

Tags: android, sql, database, sublist, sugarorm

I am using Sugar ORM, which is actually a library for SQL database operation. My database has over 4000 records, and I would like to retrieve 500 records from it, say the 501th to 1000th record.

The extraction of 500 records are as follows:

```
db_record_listing = Records.findWithQuery(Records.class, "Select * FROM Records ORDER BY recordId ASC WHERE qref_canton BETWEEN '" + s_start + "' AND '" + s_end + "'");
```

However, the error logcat is as follows:

### Logcat:

```
11-25 23:29:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(28801): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select * FROM Records ORDER BY recordId ASC WHERE qref_canton BETWEEN '1' AND '500'
11-25 23:29:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(28801):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-25 23:29:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(28801):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
11-25 23:29:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(28801):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
11-25 23:29:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(28801):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-25 23:29:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(28801):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-25 23:29:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(28801):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
11-25 23:29:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(28801):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
11-25 23:29:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(28801):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
11-25 23:29:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(28801):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
```

### Question:

1. What is the problem for the above? I found that if I remove the ORDER BY the code can be run properly (despite it is very slow).
2. Will the system still run through all the records and only pick those with `recordId` within the range and thereby very slow? If yes, would there be a quicker way where system would only retrieve those 500 records and no more?

Comment: Select * FROM Records WHERE qref_canton BETWEEN '1' AND '500' ORDER BY recordId ASC

Comment: @Hassan Thanks and following your advice putting to the end the code can now run properly. But why it has to be put at the back...and for question 2, do you know whether the system will loop for all records and filter those within the range, and thereby very slow as it has to loop all records?

Comment: SQLite is same as MySQL. first of all , you need to get the all records from the database, then only you can sort. right? so, inner query executed first,then the next will be executed in order. couldnt able to understand second question. sorry for that,can you ask clearly?

Comment: thanks. let me rephrase the question: that means eg total 4000 records with recordId in a mess, it will run over all 4000 records and select those 500 records with recordId within the range, and then second step is to sort these 500 records by recordId. In this regards, the system has run 4000 times plus sorting. My question would be, can it first sort the recordId, and then pick the 500 records given the range? This way system will run sorting plus 500 times only

Comment: Here, there is, where condition . So, get your records based on your where condition. That is only 1 to 500 records . In that 500 record, the system will sort.

Comment: @user3026347 thanks that means the system, based on the above `Select * FROM Records WHERE qref_canton BETWEEN '1' AND '500' ORDER BY recordId ASC`, the system just select 500 records to perform sorting...grateful if you could make it as an answer so that I can accept your answer! many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * FROM Records WHERE qref_canton BETWEEN '1' AND '500' ORDER BY recordId ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String from = "0";
    String to = "500";

    final List<PropertyTable> propertyTables = PropertyTable.findWithQuery(PropertyTable.class,
            "Select * FROM PROPERTY_TABLE WHERE mortgageprice BETWEEN  ? AND ?",from,to);
```